# how to get payment method in shopify

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

i want to run Ajax when Cash on Delivery option select, how can i get on step=payment_method shopify

i try this

```
$('input[type=radio][name="checkout[payment_gateway]"]').change(function(e) {
                $(".step__footer__continue-btn").on("click", function(e) {
                    //we got only cod here
                    var textAppend= $("#payment_gateway_id").val();
                    var gateway = $.trim($('.section--payment-method [for="checkout_payment_gateway_'+$("#payment_gateway_id").val()+'"]').clone().children().remove().end().text());
                    console.log('value of radio' + gateway);
                    if (gateway == "Cash on Delivery (COD)" || gateway == "Cash on Delivery") {
                        if (window.PClevel !== true) {
                            //my code          
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you cannot run your own Javascript during checkout like this. I might be wrong of course, but have you verified that that is even possible? How are you adding your JS code to checkout in the first place?

Comment: i want all payment method text like Cash on Delivery,razorpay, paytm.